# I have two home pages: mysite.com and mysite.com/pages/home in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi everyone and happy new year !

I have a problem, actualy i have 2 version (duplicated content) of my home page :
- mysite.com/
- mysite.com/pages/home/

I want to know how make link with cakephp who point on mysite.com/

I try this :

`$this->Url->build(['controller' => '', 'action' => '']);`
But doesn't work :/

Also, i have temporary make 301 redirection to redirect /pages/home/ to mysite.com but it's not a good solution.

Thank's you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to remove `mysite.com/pages/home/` url pattern completely and redirect all request on this to `mysite.com`.

You can define in `config/routes.php`

```
$routes->redirect('/pages/home', '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple url build: `$this->Url->build('/');`

or link `$this->Html->link('Home', '/');`

Comment: Hi, thank's for response, it's work but i have always 2 home page : mysite.com/ and mysite.com/pages/home/

Comment: yes you have, while on second  you access controller / method based url

Comment: i don't understand what you say sorry :/

Comment: But how to remove this version of url : /controller/action just for /pages/home ?

Comment: simple don't link to /pages/home, i don't understand why is that problem for you

Comment: Google consider that like two page similar ( duplicated content) and it's very bad for SEO

Comment: I say again: don't link to  /pages/home and google can't find that url! 2nd use robots nolink nofollow for that url

Comment: How you do that ? Thank's you very much